# While creating new crypto using fork need to generate smart contract?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, blockchain-fork, cryptography, smartcontracts

I have 2 questions for creating nee crypto currency using fork.

1.) I have created one new crypto coin which is called mindcoin, now should i generate smart contract for deployment my currency in market??

2.) Should i generate smart contract any other languages like php or .net?? I know about solidity but it will be preferable for ethereum..

Can you please let me know about it? It is very important for me if you give answer asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cryptocurrency(a new blockchain) is deployed by distributing/convincing people to use your node software. The genesis block can be considered a type of smart contract. Clever marketing has hijacked the "smart contracts" buzzword to mean hosting your code on a network that works exactly like AWS but with worse performance and higher price.
2. This is not an ethereum forum and nor are ethereum contracts really "smart". They rather dumbly execute the stored logic in a centralised manner. The beauty of a true smart contract is that it can be written in any language and it auto-deploys itself because it arose from a use-case. Eg, multisig